# In a Banach space, the closed convex hull of weakly compact set is weakly compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, convex-hulls, weak-topology

I am wondering if the following statement is true

> Let $X$ be a weakly compact subset of a Banach space $E$ (not necessarily reflexive), then the closed convex hull of $X$ is a weakly compact subset of $E$ ?

Any answer or literature related to that would be most welcome.

Comment: Yes. It is known as the Krein Smulian Theorem. Diestel's *Sequences and series in Banach Spaces* provides an outline of a proof in an exercise (page 29).

Comment: @DavidMitra Please consider writing your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The result is known as the Krein-Šmulian Theorem.  A proof can be found in Dunford and Schwartz' *Linear Operators Part I* (V 6.4). An outline of this proof (I believe) is given in exercise IV.3 of Diestels' *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*.

According to Dunford and Schwartz, the result was first shown in the separable case by Krein (*Sur quelques questions de la géométrie des ensembles convexes situés dans un espace linéaire normé et complet*. Doklady Akad. Nauk SSSR (N.S.) 14, 5-7 (1937))
and in the general case by Krein and Šmulian (*On Regularly convex sets in the space conjugate to a Banach Space*). Ann. of Math. 41, 556-583 (1940)).